# Python: run multiple scripts from a parent script where you can also set the variable values

Tags: python, file, execution

I have a few Python files that I want to execute sequentially in order to get an output and now would like to automate this process. So I would like to have a parent script from which I can execute all my child scrips in the right order. Also, I would like to execute one of the files twice but with two different date variables and would like to store the outputs in two different folders. How do I create such a parent script in Python?

For example I want to execute `file1.py` first and the date (a variable in `file1.py`) should be `date1` and the output should be stored in `dir1` and then I want to execute `file1.py` again but this time the date should be `date2` and the output should be in `dir2`. And the I want to execute `file2.py`.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily run python scripts from another python scripts using subprocesses. Something like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("script2.py some_argument")
```

Problem with using subprocesses - it's quite annoying to get results from it (you can print results from the script and then get them in the parent file, but still).

Better solution - save middle results in some database (like simple SQLite file), so you use your main script to initiate child scripts, but get arguments from the database and write child script results to the database too. It's quite easy and could solve your problems (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

For example, to save some variable in the SQLite database, all you need is:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create table (no need if it was created before)
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE example_table
                  (variable_name, variable_value)
               """)
# Save changes
conn.commit()

# Insert data
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO example_table
                  VALUES ('some_variable', 'some_value')"""

# Save changes
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how would I pass a value to a variable (in this case date1 to the date) in my child python script (script2) with subprocess? Also, if I want to execute two scripts do I just write subprocess.Popen("script2.py some_argument") and then subprocess.Popen("script3.py some_argument")?

Comment: You can send it as an argument through the Popen, or add the variable to the db and get it from there in in the `script2.py`. You can run as many subprocesses as you want.

Comment: If I send it as an argument in Popen what would it look like exactly? subprocess.Popen("script2.py" args=date1)? What is the syntax? And if I want to pass my Popen not just date1 but say for example also var1 what would this look like? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The syntax looks `subprocess.Popen("script2.py some_argument")`. You can send some string instead of `some_argument`. The whole idea - Popen simulates `python script2.py ***` command from the command line. So, you can send some text argument with it, and than get it in the child script with something like `argparse`.